# addEventListener('click') not working on a button to close a modal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I have a modal that does not seem to want to close when clicking the close button. This what my current code looks like to show and close the modal as well as adding the modal-backdrop into the DOM and removing it.

```
const $ = document;

class Selectable {

    addElement = () => {
        const html = '<div class="modal-backdrop show"></div>';
        const body = $.querySelector('body');

        body.innerHTML += html;
    };

    removeElement = elementClass => {
        let element = $.querySelector('.' + elementClass);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    };

    showModal = () => {
        const modal = $.getElementById('modal-finish');
        const body = $.querySelector('body');

        modal.classList.add('show');
        body.classList.add('modal-open');

        this.addElement();
    };

    closeModal = () => {
        const modal = $.getElementById('modal-finish');
        const body = $.querySelector('body');

        modal.classList.remove('show');
        body.classList.remove('modal-open');

        this.removeElement('modal-backdrop');
    };

    init() {
        // Look Up Button
        $.getElementById('btn-look-up').addEventListener(
            'click',
            this.showModal,
            false
        );

        // Close the Modal
        $.querySelector('.modal-close').addEventListener(
            'click',
            this.closeModal,
            false
        );
    }
}

const Selectables = new Selectable();
Selectables.init();
```

I have a feeling it's because the clickEvent is being registered straight away or something but I'm not completely sure.

Basically the modal opens but the close button is not functioning at all.

I've only ever used jQuery before to do JavaScript so I am using `const $ = document;` to ease the change over to standard JavaScript.

Comment: Is your `.modal-close` button available in the dom when you are registering the listener.

Comment: Yes but the `<div>` it is inside has `display: none` when loaded

Answer (score -2):

Try below Code:

Try it

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});